# How to populate data from one input box to another when both have different ng-models?

Tags: angularjs

Angularjs newbie here..
I have two input boxes,

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.d_oad1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.c_oad1">
```

then I have

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.d_oad2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.c_oad2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.d_oad3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.c_oad3">
```

and so on...

I need to populate value from the first input box to the next, while keeping the second input box's update independent. For example, I need to populate data from input box with ng-model d.d_oad1 to d.c_oad1, similarly, d.d_oad2 to d.c_oad2 and so on..
It would have been easy if I could use the same ng-model for both, however that is not possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to begin, whatever gets changed in input1 will be stored in variable1(`d.d_oad1`) and whatever is changed in input2 will get stored in variable2(`d.c_oad2`), to create the below functionality needed.

First we define an `ng-change` which runs whenever the `ng-modal` value changes (i.e. d.d_oad1) and call a function call `copy()` and pass the value of variable 1(`d.d_oad1`) to the function.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.d_oad1" ng-change="copy(d.d_oad1)">
```

So inside this copy function we can write the functionality needed.

**Copy functionality:**

```
$scope.copy = function(val) {
    $scope.d.c_oad2 = angular.copy(val);
  }
```

**Snippet:**

Here the copy function will receive the value of variable1 in the first arguement and assign it to the second arguement.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.d = {
    d_oad1: "",
    c_oad1: "",
    d_oad2: "",
    c_oad2: "",
    d_oad3: "",
    c_oad3: ""
  }
  $scope.copy = function(str, val) {
    var key = "c_"+str.split("_")[1];
    $scope.d[key] = val;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.d_oad1" ng-change="copy('d.d_oad1', d.d_oad1)"><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.c_oad1"><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.d_oad2" ng-change="copy('d.d_oad2', d.d_oad2)"><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.c_oad2"><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.d_oad3" ng-change="copy('d.d_oad3', d.d_oad3)"><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.c_oad3">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but I actually have multiple such text fields, i.e., <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.d_oad2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.c_oad2">
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.d_oad3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="d.c_oad3">..

any way I can make it work for all of them?

Comment: @AbhishekAcharya Well you should provide the whole HTML right and tell the problem you are facing?

Comment: @AbhishekAcharya can you share the object used to show the inputs? we can just loop through the objects and store the value!

Comment: @AbhishekAcharya I have updated my answer for updating all the outputs when input1 is given, can you check?

Comment: @AbhishekAcharya Does this help you?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers @Naren Murali, but what I actually need is the value from c_oad1 to be copied to d_oad1 only. Similarly, the value from c_oad2 to be copied to d_oad2 only. And so on...

Comment: @AbhishekAcharya Sorry for not reading the requirements properly, check my solution now!